# Float Right Image in an SVG

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve this look:
[image: a svg image floated]

- The circled element is an image element within an SVG element.
- I'm using the [Bootstrap 4 album example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/album/)
- I've tried adjusting margins, padding and float:right of the image element, but to no avail.

  ```
             <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
           <title>BROKENBLADE</title>
           <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#222" />
           <image class="profile-img" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/solomid-resources/tsm-gg/newtsmgg/players/brokenbladelarge.png
             "></image>
           <image class="role-icon" href="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/leagueoflegends/images/e/ef/Top_icon.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/50?cb=20181117143602
           "></image>
  ```

This is my code: https://codepen.io/sneaky9/pen/PozodRq

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be using [SVG2](https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/#positioning-svg-elements), you could achieve that effect by adding this to your CSS:

```css
svg > image.role-icon {
  x:100%;
  transform: translate(-50px,0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50px,0px); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50px,0px); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: translate(-50px,0px); /* Opera */
  -moz-transform: translate(-50px,0px); /* Firefox */
}
```